# My time data "does not match format". How to properly format my datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, to-date

I'm using a pandas dataframe, in which I wish to format one column to be datetime objects. The "object" strings look like this: 2009-01-01T00:00:01+02:00

I have tried to format the column with `to_datetime(dataset["Datetime"], format = "%Y/%m/%d T %H:%M:%S %z")`

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep = ";", header = "infer")
dataset["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["Datetime"], format = "%Y/%m/%d T %H:%M:%S %z")
```

I expect the columns to be converted to a datetime object, but instead I get an error message saying:

"ValueError: time data '2009-01-01T00:00:01+02:00' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d T %H:%M:%S %z' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible use only [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with no `format` parameter:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({
         'Datetime':['2009-01-01T00:00:01+02:00','2009-01-01T00:00:01+02:00'],
})

dataset["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["Datetime"])
```

If want specify format it is also possible, remove spaces and change `/` to `-`:

```
dataset["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["Datetime"], format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
print (dataset)

                   Datetime
0 2009-01-01 00:00:01+02:00
1 2009-01-01 00:00:01+02:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just using ```dataset["sampling_time"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["sampling_time"])``` produces the error: 
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '\ufeff2009-01-02T08:53:00+02:00'),

while adding the "format" you provided, I get this error message: 
ValueError: time data '\ufeff2009-01-02T08:53:00+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z' (match)

Comment: @Zygos - What is your pandas version? I think if upgrade to last problem should be resolved.

Comment: I used 3.6, but tried 3.7 and it worked! Thanks again.
One question; What if I need to use APIs such as tensorflow and Keras? As far as I know, they are not compatible with 3.7 yet

Comment: @Zygos - I say about pandas, not python ;) Python should be 3, but pandas 0.25.2

Comment: Ok this is strange. On Python 3.7 I have pandas version 0.24.2, whereas on Python 3.6 I have pandas version 0.25.2. Yet this only works on my Python 3.7 environment.

Comment: @Zygos - hmmm, is possible upgrade for each version?

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather not touch it any further in case it stops working again. Thanks again for your help.